# Setting parameter based on output of text file?

Tags: batch-file

I am working on code to read the output of a text file and will set a parameter (or variable?) of the number value of line 2. For testing purposes, it should read from the :NEW, but it doesn't.

This is the output of the text file:

```
var1=RANK|SCORE|NAME
var2=1|52456|NLM
var3=2|24610|ABS
var4=3|23385|ABT
var5=4|22158|ABU
var6=5|21821|ABV
var7=6|20272|ABW
var8=7|19476|ABX
var9=8|18864|ABY
```

This is what I have so far, but it obviously isn't right:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
color 0a
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (hiscores.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
)
set var

pause

set /p %var2=%

if %var2=% LSS 1|52456|NLM GOTO INVALID
if %var2=% EQU 1|52456|NLM GOTO NEW
if %var2=% GTR 1|52456|NLM GOTO SCORE

:INVALID
echo Sorry, you did not win any tickets this time!
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL

:SCORE
echo Congratulations on a new high score!
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL

:NEW
echo Congratulations on a new high score!
PING -n 3 127.0.0.1 > NUL
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments: You cannot set an environment variable name which contains `=`.

`|` is a special character which needs special processing.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q71082577.txt"

FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (SET "%%b")
SET var

SET /p "score=New score [number,name] ? "

SET "newscore="
FOR %%b IN (%score%) DO IF DEFINED newscore (SET "newname=%%b") else (SET "newscore=%%b")

SET "pos="
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims==|" %%g IN ('set var') DO IF %newscore% gtr %%i IF NOT DEFINED pos SET /a pos=%%h+1

IF NOT DEFINED pos GOTO notontable

SET pos

:: shuffle lower scores down 1 place

IF %pos% lss 10 FOR /L %%p IN (9,-1,%pos%) DO (
 SET /a from=%%p - 1
 CALL CALL SET "var%%p=%%%%var%%from%%%%%%"
)

SET var

:: put new score into table

SET "var%pos%=new|%newscore%|%newname%"

SET var

:: Now correct column1 of data

FOR /L %%b IN (2,1,9) DO SET /a c1=%%b-1&FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims==|" %%g IN ('set var%%b') DO CALL SET "var%%b=%%c1%%|%%i|%%j"

SET var
SET /a pos-=1
ECHO new position ON table : %pos%

GOTO :EOF

:notontable
ECHO NOT ON high-score table
SET var
GOTO :eof
```

Since each line of the file is of the form `var=string`, you can simply execute `SET "linecontents"` to set the `var?` values.

You are evidently maintaining a high-score table...

Get the candidate score and initials from the prompt in the format *score,initials*. I have deliberately left this unverified for format and assume the input will always be correct as it is likely to appear from elsewhere in your code.

Given that the string "input" is of the correct format, the variable `newscore` is set to *nothing* and `%%b` is used in a simple `for` which will assign each of the two comma-separated tokens in turn. The first token finds `newscore` is undefined, so assigns the first token to `newscore`. The second token - `newscore` is now defined, so the token is assigned to `newname`.

Next, a `for/f` is applied to each of the `var?` variables in turn. Since the `set` command will deliver the data in the form `var3=2|24610|ABS` and `=` and `|` are defined as delimiters, then token1..4 are "var3","2","24610" and "ABS" respectively, and these values are assigned to `%%g`..`%%j`. If the newscore input is greater than `%%i` (which contains the recorded score) then `pos` is assigned a value (table position + 1).

If `pos` is not defined, then the newly-input score is not greater than any existing scores, so its fate is to not be on the table.

Next bit is tricky.We need to copy each variable var*n-1* to var*n* to shuffle the values down and duplicate the value of var%pos%. First, the operation only makes sense if `pos` is less than 10 (which means "matches lowest high-score") so for other values of `pos`, we need to calculate which variable to move, and assign *that* variable's value to `var%pos%`.

First step is obvious - set `from` as the value 1 less than `%%p`. Then there's the complicated bit. I'm attempting to avoid `delayedexpansion` as that introduces problems of "crossing the bridge" if not invoked *ab initio*.

So - decoding the statement

```
CALL CALL SET "var%%p=%%%%var%%from%%%%%%"
```

First step is the inner `call`. Assuming `%%p` is 5 (and therefore `from` contains 4) then the set command is interpreted as

```
set "var5=%%var%from%%%"
```

because `%%p` is `5` and `%%` is processed as `%`. The inner `call` inherits its values from the caller process, where `from` is defined as `4`.

That `set` command is then re-interpreted in yet another subshell, which then substitutes for `from`, giving

```
set "var5=%var4%"
```

So the value is then set from the previous value which means the values shuffle down as is displayed by the `set var`

Then assign the new values to the appropriate entry in `pos`.

Last step is to correct the values of the first data column. This only needs to be done for 2..9 as 1 is constant. The methodology should be obvious from the techniques used and described in this epistle.